# Sony Android 11+ Icon badge crash Unknown URL content://com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider/badge

Tags: android, badge

Crash log show in firebase like this: all crash devices OS (11, 12, 13+)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider/badge
   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2192)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2157)
   at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:96)
   at qd.s$a.handleMessage(SonyAsyncQueryHandler.java:1)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:346)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:475)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

set badge code

```
  val contentValues = ContentValues()
  contentValues.put("badge_count", count)
  contentValues.put("package_name", context.packageName)
  contentValues.put("activity_name", launcherClassName)
  val asyncQueryHandler = SonyAsyncQueryHandler(context.contentResolver)
        asyncQueryHandler.startInsert(0, null, Uri.parse("content://com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider/badge"), contentValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

from Android 11, use third part app ContentProvider we need add package statement
so add 
 `<package android:name= "com.sonyericsson.home"/>`

in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<queries>` partly crash gone